# 22.04 | Google Chrome Forgets Passwords using Physical Power Button or Unexpected Shut Down

Tags: google-chrome, shutdown, 22.04

Google Chrome will forget all my passwords when:

- Physical power button (press & hold),
- 0% battery.

Powering off the system via GUI is ok.

Passwords are saved in my Google Account, not in Chrome.

**How can I fix this annoying issue?**

---

Sync is on:

[image]

Google Chrome Settings are OK:
[image]

View and manage passwords in your Google Account `passwords.google.com`:
[image]

Manage what you sync:

### [image]

### Ubuntu & Chrome info

Terminal:

```
(base) daniel@ubuntu-pcs:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

`chrome://version/`:

```
Google Chrome   103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
Revision    a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}
OS  Linux
JavaScript  V8 10.3.174.14
User agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /usr/bin/google-chrome --enable-crashpad --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
Profile Path    /home/daniel/.config/google-chrome/Profile 1
```

Comment: you can fix this by not letting your laptop run out of power. If it does, Chrome crashes and doesn't have a chance to save anything, which is why you lose data. You can always lose data if your computer runs out of power unexpectedly, so *shut it down yourself* before it dies.

Comment: It doesn't *delete passwords*, it just *doesn't save them* when it's shut down unexpectedly. If you want to sync passwords with your Google account, sign in to a Google account with Chrome, and then turn on sync. iirc you can go to "advanced sync settings" and make sure passwords are being synced

Comment: I've actually always had `Sync is on`. Check post

Comment: if you go to `passwords.google.com` are the passwords there? if so, it is a bug that may be able to be fixed by turning off sync, clearing all local data, and then turning sync back on again. And not letting your laptop die/crash.

Comment: and by "physical power button" I assume pressing and holding the power button? otherwise it's just a regular shutdown.

Comment: Yes; press & hold. `passwords.google.com` already in post

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a known bug, and if your passwords are still on passwords.google.com but not on the device, there is a workaround as follows:

1. Turn off sync to your google account
2. Select the option to remove all the synced data from your local storage
3. Turn on sync again, and let it sync all of your data

If that doesn't work, you may have to uninstall Chrome, clear all local data, and then reinstall. Of course, the obvious prevention would be to always shut down your laptop properly.

Comment: All steps as well as re-installation do the opposite of what the post sets out to achieve. Could you link sources of the known bug?